# RDP connection gives nca_s_fault_access_denied

Tags: networking, windows-7, network-shares, remote-desktop

I have 2 PCs on the same network with fixed IP addresses and firewalls turned off. Windows 7 Professional and the service running on a Windows 7 Enterprise editon. System running with DCOM service.

The problem is with the RDP server connection. I have checked the packets with ***Wireshark*** and get an error:

***nca_s_fault_access_denied***

I got the user privileges modified to administration rights. I can ping the 2 PCs over LAN connection.

The question is, how to fix this problem?
Has anybody the same error?

Answer (score 1):

On windows 7 you have to allow RDP from system properties. otherwise it will deny even though you are on the same network.

1. Click on Start, select Control Panel and then double-click on System.
2. Select Remote settings on the left.
3. When the window opens up, select Allow connections from computers running any version Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently in Vista, this had something to do with Remote RPC permissions. This may still continue with 7.

In the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server` add a DWORD named `AllowRemoteRPC` with a value of 1.

Edit: I realize that "Remote RPC" makes no sense.  Don't blame me for how they word it.

Comment: The problem is not on Vista. I have tried this method, nothing happened.